# Sending Complex Types as Form Parameter in C# application while calling an HTTP Post method

Tags: c#, rest, http-post, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and providing RESTful Web Services. I tested my services with GET, POST, PUT and DELETE Http methods and everything seems fine. However, I couldn't figure out how to pass data types containing some other classes or collections as parameter to POST, PUT, and DELETE requests.

For example, below is one of my POST services:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(CompanyDto input)
{
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

I am calling my services from C# desktop application. The thing is, a Compnay object contains CompanyType object as property. And I couldn't succeed to send a Company object as parameter while calling my POST PUT DELETE services. Is there a simple way to serialize data types into parameters no matter what type of properties they contain so that the Web API can automatically parse and create the corresponding data type at the server side?

Here is how I call my services:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParameter.ToString());
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

formParameter is an object whose ToString methods creates "key1=value1&key2=value2..." using reflection. Below is the code to do that:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    PropertyInfo[] properties = this.data.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        builder.Append(string.Format("{0}={1}&", property.Name, property.GetValue(this.data)));
    }
    builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1, 1);
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Could you provide code how you call your web api?

Comment: Take a look [Http Post Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521(v=vs.108).aspx)